# Altium - Invisible unrouted nets/components?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, layout

I've got a design in Altium and while routing, I moved a few resistors. They somehow accidentally got deleted and wouldn't undelete. I brought them back with an ECO, and placed them where I want them. Now, I have connection stringers going to their old location, and can't seem to get rid of them. Anyone else come across this?[image: PCB]

Edit: Design rule check does not fix this.

Comment: I have had this in the past; I seem to recall that running a design rules check from within the PCB environment fixed it.

Comment: @PeterSmith That did not work - tried already.

Comment: Another reason that this can happen is that if there is a *tiny* piece of copper assigned (assuming you had routed them previously) which you will need to significantly zoom in on to actually see, it retains the net ID.

Comment: @PeterSmith - had the same thought, tried that too. Nothing there. Selected the whole area and deleted it... Still persists.

Comment: Are you sure you have all layers turned on?

Comment: @Axis yes I have them all on.

Comment: If you run batch DRC, do you get unrouted net violations for those connections? Or is it only an online DRC problem?

Comment: @ThePhoton I do get unrouted net violations, not using online DRC.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You could enter a case/post on the Altium forums and very likely an Altium apps engineer will help you sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Ran the command Design > Clean Net List, then Tools > Reset Error Markers - that cleared up the problem.